# Virtualhost linking to wrong local site

Tags: apache, localhost

I'm using Apache and mysql to run a personal website and a personal wiki that are being referenced to external domains www.myproject.dev and www.mywiki.com respectively. I'm working off of Windows 7 64 bit.

Both sites were properly linking for some time but now both addresses link to my htdocs website, my personal site, as opposed to their respective sites.

My httpd-vhosts.conf folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.myproject.dev
ServerAlias myproject.dev
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mywiki.com
ServerAlias www.mywiki.com
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mywiki/"
```

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 myproject.dev
127.0.0.1 mywiki.com
```

Any thoughts? I apologize I'm a green user so let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: There is a difference between `www.myproject.dev` and `myproject.dev`. Your static name resolution won't work like that for the `www` variants.

Comment: Also it is odd that `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` are identical for the second host. That one won't react to the non-`www` variant this way, instead the default host will be used (which might be the effect you observe).